# Excel highlight duplicates in 2 columns, ignoring same row

Tags: excel

I have 2 non adjacent text columns that I wish to compare.  There may be duplicates in both columns but if they are not on the same row I need them to be highlighted in both columns. In the example below, Barry and Larry would both be highlighted in Columns A & C.

```
     | Col A. |  Col B.  |    Col C.   
Row1.| Harry  | London   |   Harry
Row2.| Barry  | Paris    |   Larry
Row3.| Larry  | New York |   Barry
Row4.| Gary   | Munich   |   Tom
```

If the same names are not aligned in the same row I would then cut and paste the offenders to resolve the problem. In this case the Barry in column C would be cut and inserted into row 2, forcing Larry down into row 3.  Nothing would then be highlighted.
I guess it is a conditional formatting problem but I can't get a formula to work.  I would appreciate some ideas.

Comment: Can you show us the conditionning formulas you tried?

Comment: I thought I could use the built-in conditional highlighting to highlight the duplicates and then create a function to determine the highlighted cells and then stick in a fairly simple formula to see whether both columns are the same or not.

Answer (score 0):

So if I am understanding you correctly, you want to:

1) Find duplicates and highlight them

2) Move the offenders

Is there some reason this needs to be two parts?  For moving the offenders I would run 2 loops, one to loop through the cells in column A, for each cell in column A I would loop through column C until I find the match, cut it, and paste it into the range that is two columns over from the current cell you are comparing in the first loop. you can use a range offset to find the right place to paste the name in column C.

Arrays would do this more quickly, so if you have a large number of records it would be worth looking in to.

You can use a dictionary object to accomplish both steps more easily, you can use dict.exists(value) to determine if a match exists and use those addresses for formatting, a quick google will help you with how to use them.

Honestly this seems like a homework problems so that's as far as I will go.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I simplified the dataset but it is part of a real time and working scheduling programme.  The user has asked whether the mismatches can be highlighted.  The columns are generally up to 10 rows in length.  The moves are at the discretion of the user, and so whilst the existing programme matches the rows initially as soon as the user starts moving people around mismatches start to occur.  This is when the highlighting comes in useful.

Comment: Ah makes sense.  You can use =IF(ISERROR(MATCH(A1,C:C, 0)), "No Match", VLOOKUP(A1,C:C,1,FALSE)) (note: to see if the value from column A is in column C and visa versa for your highlighting